# GHCi linker error with FFI-imported MPI constants (via c2hs)

Tags: c, haskell, mpi, petsc, c2hs

I'm figuring out how haskell-mpi works by rewriting the binding. I'm trying to re-use the MPICH installation that was set up by installing PETSc (which is working fine).
Question: `make main` gives me a correct module in GHCi, but when I request to compute commWorld, the linker complains that it can't find the MPI_COMM_WORLD symbol (which however is in scope of the makefile).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

error:

```
ByteCodeLink: can't find label
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
   MPI_COMM_WORLD
```

Main.chs :

```
type MPIComm = {# type MPI_Comm #} 
newtype Comm = MkComm { fromComm :: MPIComm } deriving (Eq, Show)
foreign import ccall "&MPI_COMM_WORLD" commWorld_ :: Ptr MPIComm
foreign import ccall "&MPI_COMM_SELF" commSelf_ :: Ptr MPIComm

commWorld, commSelf :: Comm
commWorld = MkComm <$> unsafePerformIO $ peek commWorld_
commSelf = MkComm <$> unsafePerformIO $ peek commSelf_
```

makefile:

```
PETSC_DIR_ARCH = ${PETSC_DIR}/arch-darwin-c-debug
PETSC_DIR_ARCH_INCLUDE = ${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/include

main : 
    c2hs Main.chs -C -I${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/include -C -I${PETSC_DIR}/include 
    ghci Main.hs -L${PETSC_DIR_ARCH}/lib -lpetsc -lmpich
```

mpi.h

```
 typedef int MPI_Comm;
 #define MPI_COMM_WORLD ((MPI_Comm)0x44000000)
 #define MPI_COMM_SELF  ((MPI_Comm)0x44000001)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreign import ccall "&MPI_COMM_WORLD" commWorld_ :: Ptr MPIComm
```

means that `commWorld_` will be a pointer to the variable `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. But in fact `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is not a variable, it's a CPP macro, so it's not the kind of thing that has an address at all, and this is what the linker error is telling you.

I would probably add a C file with a definition like

```
const MPI_Comm hs_MPI_COMM_WORLD = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
```

and import that in the way that you have done. Perhaps c2hs has some magic that will do this for you.

Comment: I'm thinking of the {# enum ... #} macro. However the definition above is taken from the original binding library. However I am not certain because I can't get `haskell-mpi` to build properly yet. Thank you for now

Comment: `haskell-mpi` does the same as what I suggested, see the file `src/cbits/constants.c`.

Comment: `src/cbits/constants.c` begins :

#define MPI_CONST(ty, name, defn) ty name = defn;

MPI_CONST (MPI_Datatype, mpi_char, MPI_CHAR)
MPI_CONST (MPI_Datatype, mpi_wchar, MPI_WCHAR)
...
The #define is a function macro and all the next lines are..concrete types?

Comment: There's also a {#const ...#} thing in C2HS, but it only really works in cases where what's on the right hand side of #define expands to something that looks like a constant in Haskell as well as in C (so "#define ABC 123" and "{#const ABC#}" works fine).  In this case, doing "{#const MPI_COMM_WORLD#}" splices the C code "(MPI_Comm) (void *) &ompi_mpi_comm_world" into your Haskell code, which is no use at all!  I think Reid's suggestion is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that the `CApiFFI` extension (since GHC 7.6) allows you to import not only C-level "functions" that may actually be macros, but also C-level values that may actually be macros. So you should be able to write

```
{-# LANGUAGE CApiFFI #-}

type MPIComm = {# type MPI_Comm #} 
foreign import capi "mpi.h value MPI_COMM_WORLD" :: MPIComm
```

without having to write an additional C file (GHC will do it for you).

See the documentation at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ffi.html#ffi-capi.